# pull to refresh in ionic does not refresh my list

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Using ionic pull to refresh function does not update my list. Function is called and in console data is retrieved from serve but does not refresh my list.

here is my view:

```
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="list card" ng-repeat="pickup in pickups">
                <div class="item">
                    <h2>{{pickup.title}}</h2>

                    <p>Request Date : {{pickup.added_date}}</p>

                    <p>Status :
                        <span class="positive" ng-if="pickup.status==0">On Queue</span>
                        <span class="energized" ng-if="pickup.status==1">On Process</span>
                        <span class="balanced" ng-if="pickup.status==2">On Collected</span>
                        <span class="assertive" ng-if="pickup.status==2">Cancelled</span>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="item item-body">
                    <p>Contact : {{pickup.b_contact}}</p>

                    <p>Location : {{pickup.b_location}}</p>

                    <p>
                        <a class="button circular-btn icon ion-android-done button-energized" href="#"
                           ng-click="statusData(pickup.pickupid,pickup.user_id,1)"
                           ng-if="pickup.status==0"></a>
                        <a class="button circular-btn ion-android-done-all button-balanced" href="#"
                           ng-click="statusData(pickup.pickupid,pickup.user_id,2)"
                           ng-if="pickup.status==0|| pickup.status==1"></a>
                        <a class="button circular-btn icon ion-close-circled button-assertive" href="#"
                           ng-click="statusData(pickup.pickupid,pickup.user_id,3)"
                           ng-if="pickup.status==0|| pickup.status==1|| pickup.status==2"></a>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

my controller code:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, Service, $ionicLoading, $ionicModal, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $state, $http, $stateParams) {

$scope.doRefresh = function () {
    Service.getpickup($state, $http).success(function (data) {
        $scope.pickups = data.pickup_request;
        console.log(data.pickup_request);
    })
        .finally(function () {
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        });
}
  });
```

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<ion-refresher
    pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
    on-refresh="doRefresh()">
  </ion-refresher>` did you add this ?

Comment: yes i did sorry i forgot to put in view in above

Answer (score 0):

- Have you used the ion-refresher tag in your html? I cant see it in your code. If not, use this

  ```
  <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="doRefresh()">
  ```
- Also, try manually adding the items to your list like this and see if that works. (check that data.pickup_request is an array as well)

  ```
  $scope.pickups.push.apply($scope.pickups, data.pickup_request);
  ```

Comment: i have consoled  console.log($scope.pickups); and i got the updated data but view is not updated

Comment: Can you try the push.apply?

Comment: i have used  $scope.pickups.push.apply($scope.pickups, data.pickup_request); as your suggestion but lno luck at all though $scope.pickups have updated value but does not show in view

Comment: Can you do a plunker? I can take a look at it

Comment: sorry i cant, coz its ongoing project

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issues. I have the view in pickupCtrl but i was calling the scope function in another control. Thank you every one for your guide.Thanks a lot.